# Pandas Key error when reading from the file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem.
This is my program. I use this program to find properly A and T parameters which give me properly exponential curve.

```
#otwieranie pliku
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("mgdg", sep = " ")
#przypisanie do zmiennych t -czas, C - C 
t = data["czas"]
C = data["C"]
#jak wyglada zaleznosc C od t?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t,C)
plt.show()
#funkcja do optymalizacji
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(t, A1,A2,A3,T1, T2, T3, T4):
    return A1 * np.exp(-t/T1) + A2 * np.exp(-t/T2) + A3 * np.exp(-t/T3) +(1-A1-A2-A3) * np.exp(-t/T4)
#sama optymalizacja, p0 zawiera parametry początkowe
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(func, t,C , p0=np.asarray([0.23,0.40,0.1,253,8,4600,1400]))
#do P zapisuje zaokrąglone parametry
P  = [round(x,2) for x in params]
#jak sie dopasowalo?
plt.plot(t,C)
plt.plot(t,func(t,P[0],P[1], P[2], P[3], P[4], P[5], P[6]), c = "red")
plt.show()
```

This is a fragment from my file

```
0 1
1 0.756897
2 0.712127
3 0.679612
4 0.653257
5 0.630961
6 0.611496
7 0.594308
8 0.578927
9 0.564992
10 0.552246
```

This is my error

```
(anaconda_env) jakub@jakub-Z370-HD3P:~/czasy_wiazan/Adrian$ python exp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/anaconda_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'czas'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/czasy_wiazan/Adrian/exp.py", line 5, in <module>
    t = data["czas"]
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/anaconda_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/anaconda_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'czas'
```

Why does this error occur?
I'm using Anaconda, Python 3.9, pandas, numpy and matplotlib. What should I change?

Comment: Column name in the file probably. In the example you gave the columns are `[0, 1]`, but you are asking for column `"czas"` which raises a `KeyError` in pandas, since it doesn't exist in the dataframe, as you might see from the exception traceback

Comment: There is no column "czas" in your file. Only columns 0,1 exist. If you want to use "czas" and 'C' as columns you must rename them as below: df.columns=['czas', 'C']

Comment: Thank you so much you are the best!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't have a column named czas. One way to check your column names is to type `list(data)`. You should see a list of all of your column names. If you need to rename columns in your DataFrame, see this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no column "czas" in your file. Only columns 0,1 exist. If you want to use "czas" and 'C' as columns you must rename them as below, before calling them:

```
df.columns=['czas', 'C']
```